# Bitwise-operator standard for different sized variables

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

```
int8 a = <some value>;
int16 b = <some value>;
a |= b;
```

- What is the defined behaviour for this example?
- Will `a` be threaded as a 16-bit integer?
- Will `b` drop the 8 most significant bits?
- Will both of them use the register size and drop all most significant bits  it cannot assign?
- Is it undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As on most common systems<sup>†</sup> (all I've ever used), both `int8_t` and `int16_t` have lower conversion rank than  `int`, both operands will be promoted to the latter.

Then, the `operator |=` operates on those two (commonly 32 bit) `int`s and in the last step, the resulting `int` is converted to `int8_t`. If the result does not fit into `int8_t`, `a`'s value is implementation defined. Usually, it just drops the extra bits.

---

<sup>†</sup> Actually, that holds on all systems as `int` is at least 16 bit and `long` at least 32 bit, so neither of the types you use can have a rank greater than `int`.

Answer (score 3):

There will be integral promotion happening here. `uint8_t` will be promoted to **signed** `int`, as well as `uint16_t` value, and then converted back to `uint8_t`.

Comment: Will a `uint16_t` value not change its sign when promoted to a signed 16-bit int, or does that not change with integral promotion?

Comment: @Broxzier The value will not change provided `int` is more than 16bit (since every unsigned 16bit number is representable in more than 16bits with two's complement. If `int` is 16bit (minimum required by C++ standard), it will actually be converted to unsigned int.